# No Objectbox desktop browser

Tags: objectbox

So I've started writing an app with ObjectBox as a web app, and got to the point I want to look at what I've saved, and I suddenly realised that the ObjectBox browser only seems to support Android. Can this be true that Objectbox has no means on the desktop to look inside the database? It's just a black box unless you write code?

Comment: Yes, the data browser is only available for Android devices right now. What platform would you want to use it on? I'm assuming you are writing a Java/Kotlin server application? Or put differently: what ObjectBox library are you using?

Comment: Well.. windows now. Maybe Linux later.  I thought all Java platforms are the same. Since Android is a Java platform, and the data browser is a web thing (not gui), I don't get how you managed to make it single platform... But then again I'm not an expert on Android.